# Hibernate criteria use alias inside restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

I have two classes where second class is property of first one. For example

**Payout**

```
class Payout{

int id;

Batch batch;

}
```

**Batch**

```
class Batch{

int id;

Date closedDate;

}
```

I want to fetch payouts with batch is `null or batch.closedDate is null`;

I wrote

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Payout.class, "payout")
.add(or(isNull("payout.batch"), and(isNotNull("payout.batch"), isNull("payout.batch.closedDate"))));
```

Here it doesn't work as there is no joining, but if I create alias on the top for batch then criteria is filtering only if payout has batch. How can I write criteria without alias for property but filter with property's property?

Answer (score 0):

After reading for some time I found the solution.
`Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Payout.class)
.createAlias(Payout_.batch.getName(), "b", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
                .add(or(isNull(Payout_.batch.getName()), isNull("b." + Batch_.closed.getName())));`

As I told in the question normal join is default in createAlias function and it takes payouts that has batch. But with JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN it looks for only batch that's id is equal to payout.batch.id if it exits.